# Were Japanese authorities cracking down on adult themed entertainment in preparation for the 2020 Olympics?

Tags: sport, japan, media, culture

From a [Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/26xk7w/why_is_tokyo_cracking_down_on_perverted_animes/):

> Getting quite a few news about Tokyo cracking down on Lolis, hentai, hentai games, boob sizes, cosplay conventions and recently have their eyes set on an Imouto theme cafe...
>
> What's going on? There are rumors that all this is happening because of a Christian conservative group in Japan but there's really no evidence for it...
>
> Anyone know what's going on?

Some of the reply posts suggest that it's related to the 2020 Olympic games and the image of Japan with the western world.

Is there any truth in the claim that Japanese authorities started "cracking down on" those types of entertainment/media?